# Facebook: How to post on group on behalf the owner page Name and Logo of the page(C#)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-group

I have FB Fan Page (i'm one of the admins).
on behind this page, we have 3-4 groups.

when i publish post on this group (in facebook), i can post on behalf the name and logo of the page (not my private profile).

when i post by code (c#), every post is published on behalf my private profile and not the page name and logo.
what i need to do?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if that's actually possible - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#publish only mentions using a user access token, not a page token. You'd have to check if the latter actually works.

Comment: hi @cbroe, thanks for your answer! i tried it, is working, but the post is published on behalf my private profile, and not on the Page Name and Logo profile :(
and when i tried to get token page to publish, the code return me error eith the group id or the permissions :(

Comment: Then what you want appears to be not currently possible via API.

Comment: @cbroe Thanks!.